# Does the event "onWindowFocusChanged" work for Widgets on Home screen?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I am a biginner to Android development.

In iOS, the widget receives View lifecycle events when seen.
Similarly, if the event "onWindowFocusChanged" works for Widgets in Android Homescreen ? If so can someone provide me any tutorials.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the author of the app widget — in other words, you are the one with the `AppWidgetProvider` class — then you do not receive this event.

If you are the host of the app widget, such as the home screen, you will receive this event. App widgets are ordinary views in the home screen's UI, and so the home screen will receive normal events.